# multiple post requests using wget and same base-url

Tags: http-headers, wget, json

wget has nice option that lets you allow downloading multiple files from same location

(I mean combination of `--base` and `--input-file`)

Advantage of this, is that if possible wget tries to reuse opened socket/connection.

I was wondering if it's possible to do multiple POST request using wget.
(I probably end up writing it in python, as I wasn't able to find such use in wget's docs)

i.e. inside input file I would have post data (json in my case):

```
{"results":1} 
{"results":2}
```

and request like:

```
wget --header "Content-Type: application/json" -i input.data http://example.com/api/data
```

Answer (score 2):

I think your are looking for `--post-file` parameter. `-i` is used for the `GET` method (providing an URL list), not `POST` :

```
wget --header "Content-Type: application/json" --post-file input.data http://example.com/api/data
```

[You can refer to man page](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html)

An alternative could be to use `curl` :

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d @input.data  http://example.com/api/data
```

[You can refer to man page](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html)

Comment: not really, both --post-file, and -d for curl, specify file that will be send in a single request, what I hoped to have is a single file with post data for multiple requests :/

Comment: Not sure to get why you need multiple request when only one should be enough...You certainly have your reason but i would be glad to know about them. By the way, a script using a `for` loop request for each line in file will produce a request for each iteration...

Comment: yes, I know I could simply do for. As I've written in content (regarding --input-file): "Advantage of this, is that if possible wget tries to reuse opened socket/connection."
I had some data that I wanted to download, and result differ only when different post data is being sent.